# Perl: problems with keys in hash and regular expression

Tags: regex, string, perl, file, hash

Sorry to post another question that is similar to the question that I posted earlier. I realised that my question is not very clear and it might have led to some misunderstanding in the answers. So I thought of rephrasing it and ask again.

My task is to read in 2 files (base config file and config file). Both files can have any number of lines. The order of the lines need not be in sequence. I need to ignore things after "!" and "^". However, I am stuck at the part on ignoring the "!" and "^". I am able to store each line into keys in a hash (without the things after "!" or "^") but it fails when I am comparing.

For example, if I have a line "hello!123" in the file, I need to store only "hello" in the hash and compare the string "hello" with another key from another hash. If there is a "hello" key in the other hash, I need to print it out or put it into another hash. My program can only put the "hello" from the line "hello!123" but failed at the part when it is comparing with another key in the other hash.

I have checked my regular expression by writing another short program that just takes in user input and remove the things after "!" and "^" symbols and compare with another key of the other hash.

Here is my faulty code:

```
my %common=();
my %different=();
#open config file and load them into the config hash
open CONFIG_FILE, "< script/".$CONFIG_FILENAME or die;
my %config;
while (<CONFIG_FILE>) {
    chomp $_;
    $_ =~ s/(!.+)|(!.*)|(\^.+)|(\^.*)//;
    $config{$_}=$_;
    print "_: $_\n";
    #check if all the strings in BASE_CONFIG_FILE can be found in CONFIG_FILE
    $common{$_}=$_ if exists $base_config{$_};#stored the correct matches in %common
    $different{$_}=$_ unless exists $base_config{$_};#stored the different lines in %different
}
close(CONFIG_FILE);
```

Does anyone has the same problem as me before? What do you do to solve it?

Comment: How exactly does it fail in "failed at the part when it is comparing with another key in the other hash"? Do you mean that every line gets printed? (That is because the print is not conditioned.) And your regex replace will work, but it is better written as `s/[!^].*//;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what your problem is Sakura, but I think it may be that you aren't finding matches between the `$config` and `$base_config` when you should. I suspect this may be because of leading/trailing whitespace, and suggest you write

```
while (<CONFIG_FILE>) {
  s/[!^].*//;           # Remove comments
  s/^\s+//;             # and clear leading
  s/\s+$//;             # and trailing whitespace
  next if length == 0;  # Ignore empty lines
  $config{$_} = $_;
  print "_: $_\n";
  if ( $base_config{$first} ) {
    $common{$first} = $first;
  }
  else {
    $different{$first} = $first;
  }
}
```

You also need to make sure that `$base_config` has the same treatment before you compare its values.

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly now. I didn't take into account of leading/trailing whitespace and that lead to the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sakura I have noticed a couple of mistakes in my code. Firstly that there may be whitespace in a line between the end of the data and the comment that would incorrectly be left untouched; and secondly that after removing all comments and whitespace there may be nothing left, and an empty string shouldn't be stored as a valid key. I have amended my answer and urge you to copy the changes into your own code. My apologies for these errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %common=();
my %different=();
#open config file and load them into the config hash
open CONFIG_FILE, "<", "script/".$CONFIG_FILENAME or die;
my %config;
while (<CONFIG_FILE>) {
    chomp;

    my ($first,$last) = (split(\!| \^,$_,2);

    $config{$first}=$first;

    print "_: $first\n";

    #check if all the strings in BASE_CONFIG_FILE can be found in CONFIG_FILE
    if ( exists $base_config{$first} ) {
            $common{$first}=$first; #stored the correct matches in %common
    } else {
        $different{$first}=$first; #stored the different lines in %different
    }
}
close(CONFIG_FILE);
```

This is the approach I'd take - please note the code is untested and I've only just woken up :)  You may have to fix a couple of things (near the split line at a guess...) but the idea is valid.

Comment: Thansk for your rapid response! I have fixed the syntax errors near the split. However, I still get the same error as my code. >.<

Comment: `(split(\!| \^,$_,2);` is nonsense and I suspect you meant `split /!|\^/, $_, 2;`